# Asp.net Core Controller is refreshed in every http request from Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I have a question regarding the controller in Asp.net core to collect names, which looks like

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private List<string> names = new List<string>();

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("SendName")]
    public bool SendName(string name)
    {
        this.names.Add(name);
        return true;
    }
}
```

In browser, I use JavaScript (Angular2) to send name

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
this.http.post('http://localhost/Home/SendName/', JSON.stringify({name: name}), { headers: headers }).toPromise()
        .then(res => res.json().data)
        .catch(e=>alert(e));
```

Now, names can be sent to the controller. However, every time when the JavaScript is run, the controller will be refreshed and names property in the controller will be empty. Therefore, I am not able to store any data in the controller. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every request to the controller will create a new instance of that controller, so your fields will be recreated.

You can to create a singleton service an use it in your controller to hold the names.

In the `Startup` register a service like

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
```

inject in the controller and use that service to hold `names`. It is a singleton service an will be created once for the application.

Answer (score 0):

1. A Controller is created for every request by the ControllerFactory (which by default is the DefaultControllerFactory) [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultcontrollerfactory.aspx).
2. Agree with Suren, another way is u can also store the name property in a static class.
3. Make a demo case, I request two times, and below pic is the result. Maybe help u:)

   [static class result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOVHf.png)